# Where is the race condition in this fs.readdir function?

Tags: node.js, race-condition, fs

I would like to list all folders in a directory and at the end list how many folders there are.

This is my code:

```
fs.readdir(dir, (err, folders) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        let folder = folders[i];

        fs.stat(dir + '/' + folder, (err, stats) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);

            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(folder);
                count++;
            }
            if (i >= (folders.length - 1)) {
                console.log('folders: ' + count);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The code should:

1. Read the directory
2. Increment `count` for each folder in the directory
3. When the directory read has finished, log `'folders: ' + count`

In most cases this does work and I get this:

```
...
2016-12-20--09-59-12
2016-12-20--09-59-13
2016-12-20--09-59-14
folders: 86
```

Sometimes though I get this:

```
...
2016-12-20--09-59-12
2016-12-20--09-59-11
2016-12-20--09-59-14
folders: 85
2016-12-20--09-59-13
```

Where is the race condition happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that the race condition happens because `i` can finish incrementing before all the `fs.stat`s have finished executing, because it increments outside of `fs.stats`'s callback.

I therefore need a separate variable (`j`) to keep track of all the `fs.stats`s completions, and only when *those* have finished incrementing can I list `count`.

Here is the correct code:

```
fs.readdir(dir, (err, folders) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    let count = 0,
        j = 0; // this bad boy!

    for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        let folder = folders[i];

        fs.stat(dir + '/' + folder, (err, stats) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            j++; // j, unlike i, only gets incremented *inside* the async function

            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(folder);
                count++;
            }
            if (j >= folders.length) { // check j, not i
                console.log('folders: ' + count);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now the output is consistently:

```
...
2016-12-20--09-59-13
2016-12-20--09-59-11
2016-12-20--09-59-14
folders: 86
```